# How can I get current group id (or community id) in liferay (java)?

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin

I'm developing portlet with Vaadin in Liferay 6 and I need to get the ID of the community where the portlet is located. How is it done?

Answer (score 11):

There is no Community entity in Liferay, it's just another kind of group (see `GroupConstants`)

If you have access to a `ThemeDisplay` object I think this will give you the Id of the community

```
long id = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId();
```

In a struts action you can get ThemeDisplay like this:

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = 
     (ThemeDisplay)request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
```

where `request` can be a `RenderRequest` or an `ActionRequest`.

Comment: Thanks, but themeDisplay isn't working, I tried it already. Eclipse says "themeDisplay cannot be resolved". I can fix it by creating variable themeDisplay, but is has to be initialized first, and I can only initialize it to null. Naturally it won't work if it's initialized to null. Thanks - Pat

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you access a ThemeDisplay object.

Comment: Hi,I got it working after a while. I had to implement PortletRequestListener and initialize that themeDisplay in onRequestStart -function! Thank you very much mate!

Comment: I think you mighthave done too much there, themeDisplay is a pretty central Liferay class and is generally available everywhere without too much work. Where are you accessing it from?

Comment: Thanks Bedwyr, themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId() was my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who use Spring MVC as Liferay portlets add this to the ControllerClass

```
     @ModelAttribute("tD")
    public String getThemeDisplay(RenderRequest req) {
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) req.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        return themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages();
    }
```

To refere to an image in jsp just add

```
<img src="${tD}/[image-path] />
```